# Trying to get data from excel then store it inside array and later print it

Tags: java, arrays, excel, for-loop

I am trying to read data from an excel file. When i run the below code it runs without any error but won't give any data. When i checked the code i found that the global variable rownum is not initializing and giving the default value which is 0. But inside the getData(int i) method the rownum is giving a value of 14. 
I am trying to get all string data available in excel file by using getData(int i) method and later trying to store them inside data[] array. Again inside the setData method i am trying to copy all item stored inside the data[] array to a string value. 
Can anyone please help. I am new to java.
   package com.selenium;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class DataFromExcel {
  String[] data = new String[15];
  static int rownum;

 public String[] getData(int i) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
   File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\ScreenShot\\Excel.xls");
   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
   Workbook excel = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
   Sheet sheet = excel.getSheet("Data");
   rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
   System.out.println(rownum);


     for(int j=1;j<=rownum;j++){
         Row row = sheet.getRow(rownum);
         while(row != null){
         if(row.getCell(j) != null){
         String cell = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
         while(cell != null){
             data[j]=cell;
             System.out.println(data[1]);
         }//while cell
        }//if row 
      }//for  
     }//row while
    return data;
   }//getData 
  public String setData(int i){
      String value = null;
      for(i=1; i<=data.length;i++){
          value =data[i];
      }//for setData
    return value;
  }//setData

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    DataFromExcel get = new DataFromExcel();
    System.out.println(rownum);
    get.getData(1);
    if(get.data != null){
    System.out.println(get.setData(1));}
 }//main
}// DataFromExcel
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know **(I expect so)** that the execution of the program is beginning from `main()` method.Now,when you are calling the `getData(int i)` method,then at that point the `rownum` is zero(obviously no code is modifying it) but thereafter you called `getData(int i)` with argument  which then changes the value of rownum due to the instructions given inside it ,try to add another `System.out.prinltn()` as the end line of `main()` method and print the value of `rownum.`